# How can i stop timer code

Tags: python

```
def data():

    a=0
    a+=1
    print(a)
    #if a==5:
      #sys.exit()
    b=threading.Timer(3, data) 
    b.start() 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    data()
```

①I want to try stop this code about 15 seconds
(Actually,I  need to stop the time is about 16200 second, and it's must be very precise )

(i want to know is there a better timer code?)

i have tried many times to make `i` to be `5`,but i don't know how to do

`a` will be zero everytime.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're wanting from the question, and you're asking multiple things - try to be more precise about a _single_ issue you have.

Comment: @kovac Please edit your question to fix misspellings and be more precise. You got two answers right now but you even didn't made a substantial comment on them. Effectively this is wasting people's time here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the multithreading is about, but if you just want the code to stop in ~15 seconds, I would try this:

```
import time
import sys
def data():
    start = time.time()
    while (start-time.time()<=15):
        #code
    sys.exit()
```

I don't know what the `i` is, or what it's keeping track of, but this should work!

Comment: Sorry, it's a. Actually, i want the code stop  in  16200 seconds.

Comment: In that case, just replace 15 by 16200! Also, can you explain a little further about what `a` is? Is it just an incrementor?

Comment: i just want `a` increase when funtion run . 1, 2 ,3 ,4 ......5 . Then it stop the code. I know this is not a good code. But i just try to think how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

About stopping the code for 15 seconds, Why don't just use time.sleep() and about exit the sys.exit() will do the trick like:

```
import time 
import sys

def data():

    a=0
    a+=1
    print(a)
    time.sleep(15) #stop the code for 15 seconds
    if a==5:
      sys.exit()
```